# Реализация простого скрипта на tk, постоянное обновление картинки

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, tkinter

День добрый, можете подсказать как реализовать окно tkinter(к примеру 200 на 200) в котором будет одна картинка(main.png, 200x200) просто обновляться по кругу? Я просто бесконечно плох в tk

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image # штуки для работы с изображениями из Pillow

WINDOW_WIDTH = 200 # ширина окна
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200 # высота окна


root = Tk() # экземпляр класса окна 
img = Image.open("main.png")
img_resized = img.resize((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), Image.ANTIALIAS) #подгоняем размеры картинки под размеры окна
pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized) # делаем так, чтобы tkinter умел работать с этим изображением
back_label = Label(root, image=pic) # создаём label, он автоматически примет размеры изображения
back_label.place(x=0, y=0) # рисуем label

root.geometry(f"{WINDOW_WIDTH}x{WINDOW_HEIGHT}") # меняем размеры окна
root.mainloop() # рисуем окно
```